# Injecting run-time parameters of IPoolable facade object thru sub-container installer

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, zenject

The problem is that I'm not getting proper values in sub-container installer constructor. For instance, if I'm creating my poolable facadeObject with factory like this: `QuxFactory.Create(3.1415);` Then in QuxInstaller constructor I'm getting 0 for a float parameter instead of 3.1415.. But I'm getting expected results if I'm not bind my `QuxFactory` like `FromPoolableMemoryPool`. So I'm confused how could I get my params in sub-container installer for further injection into sub-container's dependencies?

Here is a code from Extenject docs that I'm playing around:

I have my factory injected and I'm instantiating new instances like this

```
_shipFactory.Create(Random.RandomRange(2, 20));
```

```
public class GameInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    [SerializeField] private Object[] shipPrefabs;

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInterfacesTo<GameRunner>().AsSingle();

        Container.BindFactory<float, ShipFacade, ShipFacade.Factory>().
        FromPoolableMemoryPool(x => x.WithInitialSize(2).FromSubContainerResolve().
        ByNewPrefabInstaller<ShipInstaller>(GetPrefab));
    }

    private Object GetPrefab(InjectContext context)
    {
        return shipPrefabs[Random.Range(0, shipPrefabs.Length)];
    }
}

public class ShipFacade : IPoolable<float, IMemoryPool>, IDisposable
{
    private IMemoryPool _memoryPool;
    private float _speed;
    ...
    blah
    ...

    public void OnSpawned(float speed, IMemoryPool memoryPool)
    {
        _memoryPool = memoryPool;
        _speed = speed; //here I'm getting correct value
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _memoryPool.Despawn(this);
    }

    public class Factory : PlaceholderFactory<float, ShipFacade>
    {
    }
}

public class ShipInstaller : Installer<ShipInstaller>
{
    private readonly float _speed;

    public ShipInstaller([InjectOptional] float speed)
    {
        Debug.Log(speed); // here I'm getting 0 !, instead of Random between 2 : 20
        _speed = speed;
    }

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.Bind<ShipFacade>().AsSingle();
        Container.Bind<Transform>().FromComponentOnRoot();
        Container.BindInterfacesTo<ShipInputHandler>().AsSingle();
        Container.BindInstance(_speed).WhenInjectedInto<ShipInputHandler>();
        Container.Bind<ShipHealthHandler>().FromNewComponentOnRoot().AsSingle();
    }
}
```

Further when I'm injecting float to ShipInputHandler it injects as 0;

And I think there is a 'typo' in [documentation page](https://github.com/svermeulen/Extenject/blob/master/Documentation/MemoryPools.md#memory-pools-for-gameobjects) in this line:

```
Container.BindFactory<Vector3, Foo, Foo.Factory>().
FromMonoPoolableMemoryPool<Foo>(x => x.WithInitialSize(2).
FromComponentInNewPrefab(FooPrefab).UnderTransformGroup("FooPool"));
```

It won't work with `FromMonoPoolableMemoryPool<Foo>()`, cuz we have a parameter Vector3. It should be either `FromMonoPoolableMemoryPool<Vector3, Foo>()` or `FromMonoPoolableMemoryPool()` . If I'm correct here..

Comment: Did you ask this the makers of the asset/library you are using?

Comment: @derHugo I marked the question with Zenject tag. Hope he'll clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Since instances already created by the pool, then I have to perform my re-initialization logic within `OnSpawned(Vector3 param, IMemeoryPool pool)`.
To do that it is needed to Inject dependency, which is in my case ShipInputHandler, into ShipFacede and in OnSpawned method do something like this:

```
public void OnSpawned(float speed, IMemoryPool memoryPool)
{
    _memoryPool = memoryPool;
    _speed = speed;

    _shipInputHandler.Initialize(speed);
}
```

Or I guess it is also possible to bind this from Factory thru FromResolveGetter..